# Is there a way to Replace sting over whole table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace, null

I am trying to use replace over a whole table as the data contains 'NULLS' as it has been manipulated over time to remove certain incorrect values etc. and now contains a lot of NULLS, I want to replace all of the 'NULL' values to NULL over all of the Columns in a table.

I have thought about using:

```
Replace(Column, 'NULL', NULL)
```

where I have columns 2 - 17 (as 1 is id) but I was wondering if anyone knew how to specify all tables in a replace statement or another way of replacing all 'NULL' with NULL.

Comment: Why not fix the ETL job or script so that it handles NULLs properly? Otherwise you'll have to replace values *again* the next time you run the faulty script.

Comment: In any case you are asking to *update* the rows of a table and *set* to 'NULL' any row that contains the `'NULL'` value. Databases aren't excel sheets or word documents. You'll have to write a SET with a clause for each column you want to replace

Comment: Yes... I would have UPDATE Table SET Column = Replace(column,'','') ... How would I go about changing the ETL Job? and the data I am editing is from an excel sheet I need to make use of and store for future tasks and customers...

Comment: That would work now. Next time you import you'll have to do this again. How did you import the data? All tools have ways of handling missing or null values, or specifying that eg the `NULL` string specifies a NULL value. It would be *faster* than the update too

Comment: `Replace(column,'','')` won't do anything. You're passing a search expression with a length of 0.

Comment: @Larnu that is not what I have posted in the question is it I said Replace(Column*, 'NULL', NULL) I am aware Replace(Column, '', '') would do nothing...

Comment: No, it's not, however, you did say `Replace(column,'','')` in one your comments above. But (as I said in my answer) `Replace(Column, 'NULL', NULL)` is invalid syntax, and also wouldn't work (as you can't pass *`NULL`* for the third parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it for each column separately.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Column1 = CASE Column1 WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE Column1 END,
SET Column2 = CASE Column2 WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE Column2 END,
SET Column3 = CASE Column3 WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE Column3 END,
...
SET Column50 = CASE Column50 WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE Column50 END;
```

Note that `REPLACE(Column1, 'NULL', NULL)` would not work. The third parameter does not accept *`NULL`* as a value. Also, what would you expect that expression to do for a value such as `'Nullify'`?

*Edit: Added a dynamic script, if you want it:*

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'UPDATE [YourTable]' + NCHAR(10) +
              STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) + N'SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = CASE ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' WHEN ''NULL'' THEN NULL ELSE ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' END'
                     FROM sys.tables t
                          JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                          JOIN sys.types ct ON c.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id
                     WHERE t.[name] = 'YourTable'
                     AND ct.[name] IN ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nchar')),1,2,'') + ';'

PRINT @SQL;
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I am trying to Nullify the Values so that when I select * from the table I can see inconsistencies easier and use select * from Table where Column ISNULL instead of Column = 'NULL'

Comment: @OllieBeumkes that's what this answer does

Comment: Indeed, the query updates the values in every column to *`NULL`* is it has a value of `'NULL'` (these are not the same, one is the first is a representation of an absence of data, where as the latter is the literal string `'NULL'`). This means, after the `UPDATE` has been done, you can use the syntax: `WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: I am aware of this thank you guys for your input, I was asking if there was an automated way to accomplish this.

Comment: @OllieBeumkes No. I *suppose*, however, you could use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @OllieBeumkes fix the script. Or explain in the question itself how you imported the data. *That's* the automated way

Comment: The data was imported over a month ago and was 2/10 of the size the table is now I am not trying to import data but fix data that has been imported since the original import and appended/merged into the data and thanks to @Larnu I now know half of my NULLS are probably from replace(column, 'string', 'NULL') as I said I have made many changes and the table has grown exponentially I wouldn't like to start from scratch again...

Comment: @OllieBeumkes I've added a Dynamic SQL solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your statements

```
select 'update student set ' + column_name + ' = null where ' + column_name + ' = ''null'';'
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'student'
order by ordinal_position
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `QUOTENAME`. We've all seen some very *odd* column names out there, and if the OP has imported this from Excel, I would not be surprised to find columns with special characters or white space in their names.

Answer (score 0):

The hacky way would be to write an UPDATE statement that sets to null every column value that contains the `'NULL'`, otherwise sets it to the original value, eg :

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET 
    Col2= case col2 when 'NULL' then NULL esle Col2 END,
    Col3= case col3 when 'NULL' then NULL esle Col3 END,
    ...
WHERE Col2 = 'NULL or Col3='NULL' or ...
```

This is hacky because you'll have to repeat it every time you load the data. Databases aren't Excel sheets, there's no "search and replace all cells". There are no cells to begin with.

The correct way to fix this is to *fix* the import script so that it handles the `NULL` string as a NULL value.

If you can't do that, you could add an INSTEAD OF trigger to the table so that the `'NULL'` string is replaced with a `NULL` value, eg :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Cleanup ON dbo.SomeTable    
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(Col1, Col2, ....., ColN)
  SELECT 
      Col1, 
      case col2 when 'NULL' then NULL esle Col2 END,
      case col3 when 'NULL' then NULL esle Col3 END,
      ...
  FROM 
      INSERTED
```

Comment: I was just about to try to ask this, Thank you Panagiotis.

Comment: @OllieBeumkes this is still a workaround though that's slower than fixing the script. You lose fast bulk imports this way as the trigger will have to fire to replace the values. If the script disables triggers you'll have to run the UPDATE clause again

Answer (score 0):

This should update all nullable char columns in a database.

```
--Get all tables to update
DECLARE @Tables TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Tables
SELECT DISTINCT Table_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)       

--Loop though tables
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Tables)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @TableName = TableName FROM @Tables

    PRINT @TableName

    SET @SQL = NULL

    --Construct the update statement using the columns from information_schema        
    SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL +',','') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = CASE WHEN CAST([' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = ''NULL'' THEN NULL ELSE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] END ' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE Table_Name = @TableName AND (select columnproperty(object_id(@TableName),COLUMN_NAME,'IsIdentity')) = 0 AND is_nullable = 'YES' AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%'      

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [' + @TableName + '] SET ' + @SQL

    PRINT @SQL

    IF NOT @SQL IS NULL
    BEGIN
        --Execute the update statement
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Statement = @SQL
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NOTHING TO UPDATE'
    END

    DELETE FROM @Tables WHERE @TableName = TableName

END
```